# Syntax error while comparing timestamps in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, pg

Error: "syntax error at or near interval"

Join in question:

`... LEFT OUTER JOIN usersession e ON a.userID = e.userID AND e.lastAction >= now() interval '-4h' * 1"`

`lastAction` was created as `lastAction timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL`

The idea is, to return some nils if the session's timestamp is 4 hours older than the current time.

No idea what the deal is here, never had to compare timestamps before either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want records for the last 4 hours you need:

```
now() - interval '4 hours'
```

instead of

```
now() interval '-4h' * 1
```